# Difference between Compiling DLL library from developer command prompt or MVS in C

Tags: c, dll, compilation, visual-studio-2013

I have compiled 32-bit dll library and I have its source and header file. The library is somehow showing print dialog and allows me to print files. I've made 32-bit C# application, which calls printing function in dll and everything is nice.

However, now I need to recompile library to 64-bit (Recompiling my C# project is easy). Basicly I tried two methods.

First one was compiling from Visual's Studio Developer command prompt. This was first time compiling something using command line, so I googled what should I write. I was not attempting to specify 64-bit architecture, because I wanted to be sure that it is working. I used this command to build it.

```
cl /D_USRDLL /D_WINDLL printing.c User32.Lib WinSpool.Lib Gdi32.Lib ComDlg32.Lib /link /DLL /OUT:printing.dll
```

It made printing.dll for me, I tried to replace precompiled version I already had and I tried it using my C# app. Everything worked. So I wanted to compile it as 64-bit library. I googled and found out, that I have to use different cl.exe and link.exe located in Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\amd64. So I cd-ed to correct folder and wrote same command. I've got bunch (29) of "unresolved externals", I googled and found out that it is because I am trying to link 32-bit libraries. So I changed all *.Lib-s to C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x64*.Lib", retried and still got some (16) unresolved extarnals. Here is the list

```
/out:printing.exe
/DLL
/OUT:D:\Temp\printing\printing.dll
printing.obj
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x64\User32.Lib"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x64\WinSpool.Lib"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x64\Gdi32.Lib"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x64\ComDlg32.Lib"
   Creating library D:\Temp\printing\printing.lib and object D:\Temp\printing\printing.exp
printing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __report_rangecheckfailure referenced in function RSS_PrintFile
printing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol strcpy referenced in function RSS_PrintFileBez
printing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol strcmp referenced in function RSS_PrintFileBez
printing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol strlen referenced in function RSS_PrintFile
printing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateFileA referenced in function RSS_PrintFile
printing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ReadFile referenced in function RSS_PrintFile
printing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CloseHandle referenced in function RSS_PrintFile
printing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GlobalFree referenced in function RSS_PrintFile
printing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_LocalAlloc referenced in function RSS_PrintFileBez
printing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_LocalHandle referenced in function RSS_PrintFileBez
printing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_LocalFree referenced in function RSS_PrintFileBez
printing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol atoi referenced in function RSS_PrintFileBezFromTo
printing.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck
printing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __security_check_cookie referenced in function RSS_PrintFile
printing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __security_cookie referenced in function RSS_PrintFile
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DllMainCRTStartup
D:\Temp\printing\printing.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 16 unresolved externals
```

I managed to get rid of 4 unresolved externals adding /GS- option to compiler, but I do not know how to fix rest and I could not find any help. So I decided to use Microsoft Visual Studio to build my libary.
I've created new C++ project, set it to be a DLL library, added source and header file, compiled (using standart settings, on 32-bit). I've got bunch of warnings like this one

```
'function' : incompatible types - from 'char *' to 'LPCWSTR'
```

and simmilars and one error

```
'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
```

So I `#include _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` on first line of printing.c file. Hiting "Build" button then resulted in 1 successful and I got my printing.dll. I replaced printing.dll I've got from command line by this one and I tested dll using my C# app. Pressing print button brought "Select Printer and so" window (as before), but hitting print resulted in opening [small window with some chinese text](http://s27.postimg.org/5xfnciz4z/small.png). However, I can easily build it as 64-bit.

I would like to ask what am I doing wrong, why I can not compile C library from command prompt and why Microsoft visual studio somehow makes DLL not working.

I tried to debug DLL library compiled using MVS, but I failed. I do not know which solution should I open (C# testing app, or C DLL solution) and what to do next. C# wont show me code from another solution and even if I up debuger in DLL solution to open C# application it produces error

```
Debugginng information for "app.exe" could not be found or does not match. Skipped loading symbols for NGen binary.
```

and even if I press "Continue debugging", any breakpoint says, that it wont be hit, because no symbols were loaded.

### So Basicly

How do I get rid of "unresolved externals" errors while compiling as 64-bit using command line?

#### OR

How do I fix Microsoft Visual Studio to built working dll library (does not matter if 32-bit or 64bit)?

Comment: Recompiling a 32-bit library to 64-bit when this was never intended is a far from trivial task. From what I see here you are definitely not capable of taking this on. Seek professional help, preferably with the original author.

Comment: I see, but why compiling using Developer Command Prompt works, but compiling using Microsoft visual studio don't?

Comment: @Zereges - Why are you doing this via command-line?  Why not take a working 32-bit `Visual Studio project`, add the `X64` configuration, and rebuild?  Why are you taking the more error-prone approach instead of doing the easy thing and just create an `x64` configuration?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - As I asked in question. Doing this via command-line results in dll, that works. Doing it using visual studio results in not-working library. This is what makes me feel kinda stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I've managed to fix this issue. I gave up trying to build 64-bit version using command line and focused on fixing issue about chinese chars. I went to `Project -> Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line` to see what compiler parameters are passed. Then I went back to command line, and added previously found parameters one by one and testing if dll works. When I added `/D "UNICODE"`, the library stopped working.

This being said, adding `#undef UNICODE` or setting `Configuration Properties -> General -> Project Defaults -> Character Set` to `Not Set` fixed my issue and now I a able to compile my printing library for both x86 and x64 architectures.